# How to use Sqlite PRAGMA secure_delete on Android Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, pragma

Does someone have an example on how to use Pragma secure delete ?
I need it for my Android app.
I tried everything, but i always get an error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are trying to use it, along with the complete Java stack trace associated with your error.

Comment: FWIW, [this line of code](https://github.com/onionApps/ourbook/blob/master/app/src/main/java/onion/network/ChatDatabase.java#L48) shows how somebody is trying it. I have no idea if that code works, though it seems plausible.

Answer (score 2):

Example uses of `PRAGMA secure_delete` :-

```
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA secure_delete = FAST;",null); // Intermediate mode
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA secure_delete = TRUE",null);  // ON
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA secure_delete = FALSE", null); // OFF
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA secure_delete",null); // GET current state
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    for (int i=0; i < c.getCount();i++) {
        Log.d("PRAGMA","Result ==>" + c.getString(i) + "<==");
    }
}
```

The log from the above :-

`08-07 17:20:34.590 11030-11030/? D/PRAGMA: Result ==>0<==`

i.e. **Turned off**, *FAST also returns 0, TRUE (on) returns 1*.

*Note! All can return cursor with result 0 or 1;*

*Note! 1 or 0 for true or false respectively does not work e.g.* :-

Comment: Could it be that `db.execSQL("PRAGMA seccure_delete = FALSE")` failed because of the double 'c' ?     (note: seCCure')

Comment: Also, misspelling of PRAGMA: `near "PRGARMA": syntax error (code 1)`